# If $\frac{z^4+z^3+z^2}{(z-2)^3} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} a_n(z-2)^n$, how can I find $a_{-2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

If $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty} a_n(z-2)^n$  is  the laurent series  of the function $f(z)=\frac{z^4+z^3+z^2}{(z-2)^3}$  for  $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus\{2\}$ ,then find $a_{-2}   ?$

**My attempt** :By  Taylor  theorem, we have $f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$  where $$a_n= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz$$

$$\implies a_{-2}= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-2)^{{-2}+1}} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-2)^{-1}} dz$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\frac{z^4+z^3+z^2}{(z-2)^3}}{(z-2)^{-1}} dz$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{z^4+z^3+z^2}{(z-2)^2} dz$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i} 2\pi i({4z^3+3z^2+2z})|_{z=2} =48$$

Therefore $a_{-2}=48$

Comment: Another approach: $z^{3}=((z-2)+2))^{3}=(z-2)^{3}+3(z-2)^{2}+3(z-2)+2^{3}$ etc. You get the Laurent series without any integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series, we obtain by applying the binomial theorem

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[(z-2)^{-2}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{z^4+z^3+z^2}{(z-2)^3}}\\
> &=[(z-2)^{-2}]\frac{((z-2)+2)^4+((z-2)+2)^3+((z-2)+2)^2}{(z-2)^3}\\
> &=\binom{4}{1}2^3+\binom{3}{1}2^2+\binom{2}{1}2^1\\
> &=32+12+4\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=48}
> \end{align*}